# How convert APK arm64 to armv7 packed with UE5

Tags: android, apk, arm64, armv7, unreal-engine5

I'm working on a multi-platform Archviz with UE5. The problem is that UE5 stopped supporting armv7 and I would like my app did that.

I think it's possible but I don't know how: I'm not a developer but only a furniture designer.

I tried to make an Android packing with UE4 for armv7 and change the lib of my gradle folder of my project. I added with Android Studio in abi.gradle the correct filter following this: [How to Ensure Android APK supports 32-bit as well as 64-bit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56647103/how-to-ensure-android-apk-supports-32-bit-as-well-as-64-bit)

Then, I managed to install the app on the device, it's a Samsung Galaxy A13, but the app crashes on startup.

I hope the experts can help me because the idea of ​​switching UE5 to UE4 manually kills me because unfortunately project downgrade is not possible.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Unreal Engine would need to provide their engine binary for 32-bit Android. Given that UE deprecated 32-bit Windows support in [4.25](https://docs.unrealengine.com/4.27/en-US/WhatsNew/Builds/ReleaseNotes/4_25/#majorupgradenotes) and [UE 5 specifies 64-bit Android](https://docs.unrealengine.com/5.0/en-US/android-development-requirements-for-unreal-engine/)

Comment: @MorrisonChang I was hoping to be able to bypass the UE5 problem via Android Studio: is it not possible?

Comment: If UE5 only supports arm64 and you want armv7 support you can not use UE5.

Comment: @Robert so Android Studio use in any case UE5 and I can’t only switch the lib, okay. Thank you!